# Merge a redundant .each/.keyup jQuery script

Tags: jquery, merge

This wordcount script I inherited works well, but it just seems redundant to have the same script written twice to handle the wordcount on page load and on keyup.

Just seems like it could be cleaner and more efficient if it was written once and used in both places. I'm sure it's simple, but just can't wrap my head around how I could set that up.

```
$('.wordcount').each(function() {
    var plural_characters = '',
        plural_words = '',
        character_length = $(this).val().length,
        word_length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length,
        counter_span = $(this).parents('tr').find('.counter');

    if (character_length != 1) {
        plural_characters = 's';
    }

    if (word_length != 1) {
        plural_words = 's';
    }

    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        plural_words = 's';
        word_length = '0';
    }

    counter_span
        .html(character_length + ' character' + plural_characters + '<br />' + word_length + ' word' + plural_words);

    $(this).keyup(function() {
        var plural_characters = '',
            plural_words = '',
            character_length = $(this).val().length,
            word_length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length,
            counter_span = $(this).parents('tr').find('.counter');

        if (character_length != 1) {
            plural_characters = 's';
        }

        if (word_length != 1) {
            plural_words = 's';
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            plural_words = 's';
            word_length = '0';
        }

        counter_span
            .html(character_length + ' character' + plural_characters + '<br />' + word_length + ' word' + plural_words);
    });
});
```

I set up a basic fiddle with this script: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysgrd/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the `keyup` handler, then trigger it:

http://jsfiddle.net/F9kg5/

```
$('.wordcount').keyup(function() {

    //...

}).trigger('keyup');
```

Full code from fiddle:

```
$('.wordcount').keyup(function () {
    var plural_characters = '',
        plural_words = '',
        character_length = $(this).val().length,
        word_length = $(this).val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length,
        counter_span = $(this).parents('tr').find('.counter');

    if (character_length != 1) {
        plural_characters = 's';
    }

    if (word_length != 1) {
        plural_words = 's';
    }

    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        plural_words = 's';
        word_length = '0';
    }

    counter_span.html(character_length + ' character' + plural_characters + '<br />' + word_length + ' word' + plural_words);
}).trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: Boom! Simple. Thanks Jason!

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution as all the calculations are still needlessly being defined twice.

Comment: @rgbflawed Perhaps I should have posted the full code from the fiddle originally. The calculations are not repeated.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  Just curious for me, though... how is it being called the first time?  I can see from the jsfiddle that it is.  But how if it's only being bound to keyups?

Comment: The `.trigger('keyup')` part triggers a `keyup` event on all of the `.wordcount` elements.

Comment: Sorry, for the first time I meant, on page load.  When the page first comes in there hasn't been a keyup yet... but yet the wordcount values have still run.

Comment: `.trigger('keyup')` simulates a `keyup` event. Calling that makes the browser react as though a `keyup` has happened.

Comment: The jquery documentation may be able to explain it better than me: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd clean up this code:

```
function wordCount(object) {
    var plural_characters = '';
    var plural_words = '';
    var character_length = object.val().length;
    var word_length = object.val().split(/\b[\s,\.-:;]*/).length;

    if (character_length != 1) {
        plural_characters = 's';
    }

    if (word_length != 1) {
        plural_words = 's';
    }

    if (object.val() == '') {
        plural_words = 's';
        word_length = '0';
    }
    object.parent().siblings('.label').children('.counter').html(character_length + ' character' + plural_characters + '<br />' + word_length + ' word' + plural_words);

}

wordCount($('.wordcount:first'));

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wordcount').keyup(function(){
        wordCount($(this));
    });
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle with some more comments included:
http://jsfiddle.net/34NBT/1/